# Metal Command Buffer Internal Error: What is Internal Error (IOAF code 2067)?

Tags: swift, gpu, gpgpu, metal

Attempting to run a compute kernel results in the following message:

`Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Internal Error (IOAF code 2067)`

To get more specific information I query the command encoder's user info and manage to extract more details. I followed instructions from [this video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10616/?time=731) to yield the following message:

```
[Metal Diagnostics] __message__: MTLCommandBuffer execution failed: The commands 
associated with the encoder were affected by an error, which may or may not have been 
caused by the commands themselves, and failed to execute in full __:::__ 
__delegate_identifier__: GPUToolsDiagnostics
```

The breakpoint triggered by the API Validation and Shader Validation results in a record stack frame - not a GPU backtrace. The breakpoint does not indicate any new information apart from the above message.

I cannot find any reference to the mentioned IOAF code in documentation. The additional information printed reveals nothing of assistance. The kernel is quite divergent and I am speculating that may be causing the GPU to take too much time to complete. That may be to blame but I have nothing supporting this apart from a gut feeling.

Here is the thread setup for the group:

```
let threadExecutionWidth = pipeline.threadExecutionWidth

let threadgroupsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: (Int(pixelCount) + threadExecutionWidth - 1) / threadExecutionWidth, height: 1, depth: 1)

let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: threadExecutionWidth, height: 1, depth: 1)

commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
```

The GPU commands are being committed and waited upon for completion:

```
commandEncoder.endEncoding()

commandBuffer.commit()
commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()
```

Here is my application side code in it's entirety:

```
import Metal
import Foundation
import simd

typealias Float4 = SIMD4<Float>

struct SimpleFileWriter {
  var fileHandle: FileHandle
  
  init(filePath: String, append: Bool = false) {
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
      FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: filePath, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
    }
    
    fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: filePath)!
    if !append {
      fileHandle.truncateFile(atOffset: 0)
    }
  }
  
  func write(content: String) {
    fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
    guard let data = content.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii) else {
      fatalError("Could not convert \(content) to ascii data!")
    }
    fileHandle.write(data)
  }
}

var imageWidth = 480
var imageHeight = 270
var sampleCount = 16
var bounceCount = 3 

let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
let library = try! device.makeDefaultLibrary(bundle: Bundle.module)
let primaryRayFunc = library.makeFunction(name: "ray_trace")!
let pipeline = try! device.makeComputePipelineState(function: primaryRayFunc)

var pixelData: [Float4] = (0..<(imageWidth * imageHeight)).map{ _ in Float4(0, 0, 0, 0)}
var pixelCount = UInt(pixelData.count)

let pixelDataBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: &pixelData, length: Int(pixelCount) * MemoryLayout<Float4>.stride, options: [])!
let pixelDataMirrorPointer = pixelDataBuffer.contents().bindMemory(to: Float4.self, capacity: Int(pixelCount))
let pixelDataMirrorBuffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: pixelDataMirrorPointer, count: Int(pixelCount))

let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!
let commandBufferDescriptor = MTLCommandBufferDescriptor()
commandBufferDescriptor.errorOptions = MTLCommandBufferErrorOption.encoderExecutionStatus
let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(descriptor: commandBufferDescriptor)!
let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()!

commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(pipeline)
commandEncoder.setBuffer(pixelDataBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
commandEncoder.setBytes(&pixelCount, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.stride, index: 1)
commandEncoder.setBytes(&imageWidth, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.stride, index: 2)
commandEncoder.setBytes(&imageHeight, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.stride, index: 3)
commandEncoder.setBytes(&sampleCount, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.stride, index: 4)
commandEncoder.setBytes(&bounceCount, length: MemoryLayout<Int>.stride, index: 5)


// We have to calculate the sum `pixelCount` times
// => amount of threadgroups is `resultsCount` / `threadExecutionWidth` (rounded up)
// because each threadgroup will process `threadExecutionWidth` threads
let threadExecutionWidth = pipeline.threadExecutionWidth;
let threadgroupsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: (Int(pixelCount) + threadExecutionWidth - 1) / threadExecutionWidth, height: 1, depth: 1)
// Here we set that each threadgroup should process `threadExecutionWidth` threads
// the only important thing for performance is that this number is a multiple of
// `threadExecutionWidth` (here 1 times)
let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: threadExecutionWidth, height: 1, depth: 1)
commandEncoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadgroupsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
commandEncoder.endEncoding()

commandBuffer.commit()
commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

if let error = commandBuffer.error as NSError? {
  if let encoderInfo = error.userInfo[MTLCommandBufferEncoderInfoErrorKey] as? [MTLCommandBufferEncoderInfo] {
    for info in encoderInfo {
      print(info.label + info.debugSignposts.joined())
    }
  }
}

let sfw = SimpleFileWriter(filePath: "/Users/pprovins/Desktop/render.ppm")
sfw.write(content: "P3\n")
sfw.write(content: "\(imageWidth) \(imageHeight)\n")
sfw.write(content: "255\n")

for pixel in pixelDataMirrorBuffer {
  sfw.write(content: "\(UInt8(pixel.x * 255)) \(UInt8(pixel.y * 255)) \(UInt8(pixel.z * 255)) ")
}

sfw.write(content: "\n")
```

Additionally, here is the shader being ran. I have not included all function definition for brevity's sake:

```
kernel void ray_trace(device float4 *result [[ buffer(0) ]],
                        const device uint& dataLength [[ buffer(1) ]],
                        const device int& imageWidth [[ buffer(2) ]],
                        const device int& imageHeight [[ buffer(3) ]],
                        const device int& samplesPerPixel [[ buffer(4) ]],
                        const device int& rayBounces [[ buffer (5)]],
                        const uint index [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
  
  if (index >= dataLength) {
    return;
  }
  
  const float3 origin = float3(0.0);
  const float aspect = float(imageWidth) / float(imageHeight);
  const float3 vph = float3(0.0, 2.0, 0.0);
  const float3 vpw = float3(2.0 * aspect, 0.0, 0.0);
  const float3 llc = float3(-(vph / 2.0) - (vpw / 2.0) - float3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0));
  
  float3 accumulatedColor = float3(0.0);
  thread float seed = getSeed(index, index % imageWidth, index / imageWidth);
  
  float row = float(index / imageWidth);
  float col = float(index % imageWidth);
  
  for (int aai = 0; aai < samplesPerPixel; ++aai) {
    float ranX = fract(rand(seed));
    float ranY = fract(rand(seed));
    float u = (col + ranX) / float(imageWidth - 1);
    float v = 1.0 - (row + ranY) / float(imageHeight - 1);
    Ray r(origin, llc + u * vpw + v * vph - origin);
    
    float3 color = float3(0.0);
    HitRecord hr = {0.0, 0.0, false};
    
    float attenuation = 1.0;
    for (int bounceIndex = 0; bounceIndex < rayBounces; ++bounceIndex) {
      testForHit(sceneDistance, r, hr);

      if (hr.h) {
        float3 target = hr.p + hr.n + random_f3_in_unit_sphere(seed);
        attenuation *= 0.5;
        r = Ray(hr.p, target - hr.p);
      } else {
        color = default_atmosphere_color(r) * attenuation;
        break;
      }
    }

    accumulatedColor += color / samplesPerPixel;
  }

  result[index] = float4(sqrt(accumulatedColor), 1.0);
}
```

Oddly enough, it occasionally shall run. Changing the number of samples to 16 or above will always results in the mention IOAF code. Less than 16 samples, the code will run ~25% of the time. The more samples, the more likely it is to results in the error code.

Is there anyway to get additional on IOAF code 2067?

Comment: Have you tried creating command buffer with `encoderExecutionStatus` option in its descriptor? Or maybe using Shader Validation? Also, I think this error may happen if your command buffer is victim of another command buffers fault, so check completion handlers on other command buffers you submit.

Comment: commandBufferDescriptor.errorOptions = MTLCommandBufferErrorOption.encoderExecutionStatus



let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(descriptor: commandBufferDescriptor)!


Message printed is the same...


No other command buffers are in use at the time.

Comment: So it's a single dispatch running and nothing else and it crashes? There should be a way to retrieve breadcrumbs for encoders, here's a link to a talk about error handling: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10616/ Also, you may need to provide a bit more context so that it's easier to understand what's going wrong

Comment: Single dispatch and nothing else. I have followed the instructions in the video posted to arrive at the "more specific error" in the post. Enabling the breakpoint reveals nothing new, the Metal Diagnostics Backtraces do not point to a specific place in shader and the triggered breakpoint does not give a GPU backtrace but a recorded stack frame instead. I will update my post so that future visitors know the steps I have already taken to debug. I will add code to demonstrate my process in full.

Answer (score 0):

Determining the error code with Metal API + Shader Validation was not possible.

By testing individual portions of the kernel, the particular error was narrowed down to a while loop that caused the GPU to hang.

The problem can essentially be boiled down to code that looks like:

```
while(true) {
 // ad infinitum
}
```

or, in the case of the code above in the call to `random_f3_in_unit_sphere(seed)`:

```
while(randNum(seed) < threshold) {
  // the while loop is not "bounded"
  // in any sense. Whoops.
  ++seed;
}
```